# (C# API-Controller) return response from child-method

Tags: c#, api, controller

I got an API-Controller with several methods(Get,Delete,Post etc). Each returns a response(`IActionResult`).
These methods call a childmethod which returns a `Type` or fails.

- If the childmethod returns a type the calling method continues as
  normal.
- If the childmethod fails it should return an `IActionResult` and interrupt the calling method (the `IActionResult` has content from the method)

Now I could return a `tuple<Type?, IActionResult?>` and proceed in my caller with whatever is not null, but that code would need to be copied everytime i use this method.
Is there a better way to do this?

I read/thought about the following:

- Exception filters -> i havent tried it but seems possible. I would
  prefer to make it method-specific

Codesample (just the idea, not tested):

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("/Db/Api/{className}")]

public class API : ControllerBase
{

[HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(string className, int id)
    {
        var classType = childMethod(className); // gets the type of the class
        var entry = _context.Find(classType, id);//find entity in db
        _context.Remove(entry);
        return Ok();
    }[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(string className, int id)
    {
        var classType = childMethod(className);// gets the type of the class
        var entry = _context.Find(classType, id);//find entity in db
        return entry;
    }
}
```

Comment: The childmethod should return a type, if it doesnt it should send a notfound with some content. I could return a nullable type and check that but then i dont have the text. Or a tuple with both but then i will have more checks in the parent method which i would like to avoid. I call this function in several methods and would like to avoid copying all that code - if thats possible @RyanWilson

Comment: What about the "TryXXX" Method pattern? Have the method be like `bool TryChildMethod( out SomeType result )`. Then you can do `if( TryChildMethod( out SomeType result )) return result;`

Comment: I would have to use the "TryXXX" method pattern every time i call the method which is what i want to avoid. I also want to define the ´IActionResult´ in the childmethod. I will try to rework the post again to make it more clear aswell. @Fildor

Comment: @RyanWilson You pretty much got it, the url/route includes a class name. The classname is passed to the childmethod. The childmethod returns the type of the class or if not found an IActionResult(with further description of the error).  I Also cleaned up the post with a tuple example. Is there no way to avoid the additional code in the callerclass that tuples/serialize/contentresult would add?

Comment: @RyanWilson Im sorry I should've added a codesample. Im still testing so the above code is just the idea. To answer your question: I am getting a db entry with the class + id, so yes Im using the class returned from the childmethod. - updated the post

Comment: @sazego I think you could move all the logic of your controller methods inside of the child method and just return a `ContentResult`, if it fails to find the type, it should return `ContentResult` with a status code of 404, if it finds it and completes the CRUD operation, then return `ContentResult` with the serialized entity as the Content and Status Code of whatever is appropriate, 200, 201, etc., just do `return childmethod`. Reference: [contentresult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.contentresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: Are you striving for e.g. [this](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/04/generic-and-dynamically-generated-controllers-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) / [this](https://dev.to/guivern/build-a-generic-crud-api-with-asp-net-core-adf) ?